# Clip button to view

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, swift4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHCGz.png)So i have backgroundView (UIView) and two buttons in it.
Now i have made following code

```
 buttonBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
 buttonBackgroundView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
 buttonBackgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

@IBOutlet weak var firstbutton: UIButton!{
        didSet{
            proceedButton.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }
```

in this the view has rounded corner but the button does not have those rounded corners
How do i implement that? (so that button also get the rounded corner.
I have two buttons, so I want only the left corner of left button and right corner of right button.

I have added the image link which i want to achieve.

Comment: not a clear question. please specify.

Comment: You want to mask the view to bounds, not the button. Try this on view's layer. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410896-maskstobounds

Comment: You need set parent view's maskToBounds to True instead of the button.
Or you may set the button's layer property correctly and maskToBounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var yourView: UIView! //Create your view outlet
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        yourView.clipsToBounds = true
        yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 15 // As per you requirement 
        yourView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        yourView.layer.borderWidth = 2

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Add Following constraint
[image: Storyboard with Constraints]

Output:
[image]

This might help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `masksToBounds` property,

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstbutton: UIButton!{
    didSet{
        proceedButton.clipsToBounds = true
        proceedButton.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved.  Thanks for the help